# Interupt - microcontroller, Atmega 328p - Capturing time

Tags: c, timer, embedded, interrupt

Disclaimer - Im a big rookie when it comes to Interrupts so please if you have some errors to point out, ill be happy to hear.
Im programming a digital hall sensor that acts like a switch whenever magnet is present and I want to use a timer for it. d10 pin, PB2, supplied with 5V. [Atmega328p]
Id like to use the `oneround` as time for single round made  to calculate windspeed later on, endless loop.
Magnet Spins in a small radius , so the PIN  [ON by default] will switch off at speed anywhere between 0.1s- 1.0s, then back on of course.

 Issue Rise when I try to print the value `TCNT1`, if I  use prescaler of 256 it gives a somewhat number out - still random , but number. Now if I use 1024 prescaler It keeps adding up 1 for every time magnet is present. 

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? 
 Can I print `TCNT1` as a time difference from PIN turning back On point(which would be the 360 degree)?

 
I need to use time in ms for calculating windspeed.

```
//include user/defined libraries
#include "i2cmaster.h"
#include "lcd.h"
#include "ds1621.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

//void init_timer1();

volatile unsigned char run = 0;
volatile unsigned int oneround;


void init_timer1() {
    //______________________________// Set the Timer Mode to CTC and start timer
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
    OCR1A = 0x3D; // Set the value that you want to count to OCR1A = 0x3D;          
    PCICR |= (1 << PCIE0);
    PCIFR |= (1 << PCIF0);
    PCMSK0 |= (1 << PCINT2);
    //________________________________________________________________________________________pray  this 1010011 1001000 1001001  1010100 works
    sei();

}
int main(void) {
    // WINDSPEED"
    DDRB &= ~(1 << DDB2); //     DIRECTION REGISTER  INOUT              D10  PCINT2 OC1B     PB2     SS   PWM  CTC
    PORTB |= (1 << PORTB2); //  OUTPUT REGISTER  hIGH
    //DDRB  = 0b11111011;         //   DIRECTION REGISTER  IN OUT
    //PORTB = 0b00000100;           //   OUTPUT REGISTER

    i2c_init(); //initialization of communication
    LCD_init(); //initialization of the LCD
    init_timer1(); // Lets count those laps baby

    while (1) {                          /*  O_O KAPUT!  */

    LCD_set_cursor(1, 1);
    printf("%u            ", oneround);
        // rest of the sensors

    }


return 0;
}                                           // Main close 

ISR(PCINT0_vect) {
    if (run == 0) {
TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS12); // clear timer and stop

        oneround = TCNT1; 
    TIFR1 |= (1 << OCF1A) | (1 << OCF1B) | (1 << TOV1);
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS22) | (1 << CS21) | (1 << CS20); // set prescaler to  1024   and start timer    1sec 
    run = 1;
}

else {
    run = 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all.

```
TCCR1B |= (1 << CS22) | (1 << CS21) | (1 << CS20); // set prescaler to  1024   and start timer    1sec
```

you are using names of bits for the Timer2 (`CS2x`) and assign them to the register of timer 1 (`TCCR1x`). `CS2x` == `CS1x`, but semantically it is a error.

Please refer to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf), chapter *15.11.2 TCCR1B – Timer/Counter1 Control Register B* at page *110*.

When all three bits `CS12`, `CS11` and `CS10` are set, timer works on external clock source on T1 pin. If you want to have 1:1024 prescaler then `CS11` bit should be 0.

Next.

Pin change interrupt can fire when the logical level goes in either direction. With small occasional spikes the level can change twice, but interrupt will fire only once. So, do not forget to check the level on the input pin.

When you write

```
TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS12);
```

it does not stop the timer, because it clears only bit CS12 but bits CS10 and CS11 remain (causing the timer to continue count with another prescaler).

Also, stopping timer does not reset its value. You need to write `TCNT1 = 0;` to reset it.

Also you need not to stop the counter. Just use the full cycle to calculate the difference.

```
volatile uint16_t prev_timer_value = 0;
volatile uint16_t oneround = 0;



ISR(PCINT0_vect) {
    if ((PINB & (1 << PINB2)) == 0) { // Low level on the pin
        uint16_t tval = TCNT1; // latch the current timer value;
        oneround = tval - prev_timer_value; // calc the difference;
        prev_timer_value = tval; // remember a new val
    }
}

// To start the timer just start it in the Normal mode 
TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B = (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10); // 1:1024
```